# Shrink DT::dataTableOutput Size

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I have a shiny interface, and I use `DT::dataTableOutput` and `DT::renderDataTable` a lot. However, I wonder if there's a way to shrink the datatable's size, e.g., making the font and the table smaller. How should I do this?

Let's say I have the following code:

```
foo <- function(){
  shinyApp(
    ui = fluidPage(
      DT::dataTableOutput("table")
    ),

    server <- function(input, output) {
      x <- data.frame(1:5, 2:6)
      output$table <- DT::renderDataTable(x)
    }
  )
}
```

What options or tags should I add?

Comment: great question! I would be interested in knowing the answer too~

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Try adding `width: 75%` to your `style` parameter of the `div`:

```
div(DT::dataTableOutput("table"), style = "font-size: 75%; width: 75%")
```

Comment: No problem man. And of course you can tweak the sizes by changing the numbers, I just arbitrarily picked 75%.

Answer (score 0):

```
div(DT::dataTableOutput("table"), style = "font-size:50%")
```

for the smaller font(in UI)

Comment: But that only makes the font smaller, but didn't change the table size?

Comment: yeah i don't know about the table size lol, try some html tags