# Controlling table width in Shiny dataTableOutput

Tags: r, shiny

I am unable to control the width of a datatable I have added to a shiny app using the function `dataTableOutput()`. I've tried to use the `width` parameter within the function but it changes nothing in the output and there is no error ~ it's not telling me that it's ignoring the `width` parameter.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)

ui <- fluidPage(theme = shinytheme("Spacelab"),
            fluidRow(
              column(6,dataTableOutput(outputId = "table")),
              column(6,p(textOutput("para")))
  )
)

server <- function(input, output){

  df <- as.data.frame(matrix(0, ncol = 15, nrow = 20))

  output$table <- renderDataTable({df})

  output$para <- renderText({
    text <- rep(x = "Hello World",1000)
  })
}
shinyApp(ui = ui,server = server)
```

Comment: I don't see a `width` argument in `shiny::dataTableOutput`, but it looks like `dataTableOutput` from package DT has one.  Have you loaded the DT package after shiny?  You can also use `DT::dataTableOutput`.

Comment: If I use `DT` instead of `shiny` will the data table still be reactive?

Comment: try [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31921238/shrink-dtdatatableoutput-size)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

`dataTableOutput` does not have an argument width. You can use `column` within a `fluidRow` with argument width, supplying an integer between 1 and 12.

```
library(shinythemes)
ui <- fluidPage(theme = shinytheme("Spacelab"),
    fluidRow(
        column(
            dataTableOutput(outputId = "table"), width = 6)
    )
)

server <- function(input, output){
    df <- as.data.frame(matrix(0, ncol = 20, nrow = 5))
    output$table <- renderDataTable({df}, 
        options = list(scrollX = TRUE))
}
shinyApp(ui = ui,server = server)
```

Options from the JavaScript library DataTable can be passed directly via `renderDataTable` argument options. For example, setting scrollX to be true allows tables to scroll.

Comment: I tried using columns and updated my example accordingly, it seems like `dataTableOutput` doesn't want to cooperate

Comment: In your original example you had a large number of columns. shiny is still rendering a web page, so if the columns are too wide to fit in a subset of the pane, the table will be displayed using the portion of the page available.

Comment: In your updated example, the `textOutput` is displayed in the correct half and the `dataTableOutput` is crashing the text in the Firefox browser. What behaviour would you rather see?

Comment: I would like to the see the `dataTableOutput` contained within the specified area. I am thinking you would be able to scroll left and right to view all the columns.  I have tried placing the table within an `absolutePanel` but it didn't give the behavior I wanted.  Thanks for your help @CSJCampbell

Comment: @Collin I have updated the example to demonstrate adding a scrolling bar for the table... you need to pass the JavaScript arguments to `renderDataTable` as a list.

Answer (score 12):

If you use the "DT" R package, and the respective `DT::dataTableOutput` and `DT::renderDataTable`, you can use a "width" option with those calls, which apparently can be either a % (e.g. width = "100%") or pixels (width = 300) which should get you the control you want.

See:
https://rstudio.github.io/DT/shiny.html

Note from that page:

> Important: Be sure to use the DT:: prefix when calling dataTableOutput
>   and renderDataTable so that the DT versions of these functions are
>   guaranteed to be called, instead of the deprecated Shiny versions. If
>   you make sure to library(DT) after library(shiny), normally the DT
>   versions should just override the shiny versions if you do not use the
>   DT:: prefix (when in doubt, use this prefix, until we completely
>   remove these functions from shiny)