# show a bird's-eye view of datatable in shiny-based webpage

Tags: r, datatables, shiny, dt

The final aim is to show all the columns and rows in a page without scrolling, even making the table smaller (like zoom in). Because I'd like to get a bird's-eye view of this table, without caring about numbers in table. Thank you.

one step can be show colnames vertically in shiny-based DT::datatable as they take lots of space, though I still do not know how to implement it.

Code:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
shinyApp(
ui = fluidPage(DT::dataTableOutput('tbl')),
server = function(input, output) {
    output$tbl = DT::renderDataTable(
        DT::datatable({cbind(mpg, mpg, mpg)}, 
             options = list(paging = FALSE))

    )
}
)
```

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31923374/5894457) link could help you.

Comment: @SBista it seems works for columns only. Thank you. My final objective is to show it as a heatmap with the ability reordering any column.