# Adjusting the width of the datatable using DT in R

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, dt

This is a script for a data table that is created in R shiny.I am trying to fit the plot within the box completely by adjusting the width of the plot. Below is the script of the plot along with the box in which I am trying to fit. Please help me to adjust the width of the plot produced using datatable. Also, I don't want to increase the width of the box. A link to apossible solution would be of great help. Thanks.

**Script for datatable:**

```
r3_blood = subset(patient, handling == "Blood test" & employee == "r3")
  datatable(r3_blood, options = list(
    searching = FALSE,
    pageLength = 5,
    lengthMenu = c(5, 10, 15, 20)
  ))
```

**Script to fit table in box:**

```
box( title = "Case Summary", status = "primary", height = 
  "575",solidHeader = T, 
                          dataTableOutput("sankey_table"))
```

[image: DataTable]

Comment: You might be interested in this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31921238/shrink-dtdatatableoutput-size

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Shrink DT::dataTableOutput Size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31921238/shrink-dtdatatableoutput-size)

Answer (score 23):

1) Along with already proposed `possible duplicate` [ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31921238/shrink-dtdatatableoutput-size) where you can use `div(DT::dataTableOutput("table"), style = "font-size: 75%; width: 75%")`

2) Also you can add `scrollX = T` into your options

```
library(DT)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Basic dashboard"),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    box(title = "Case Summary", width = 4,status = "primary", height = "575",solidHeader = T, dataTableOutput("Table"))
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$Table <- renderDataTable(
    datatable(mtcars, options = list(searching = FALSE,pageLength = 5,lengthMenu = c(5, 10, 15, 20), scrollX = T))
  )
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]